# BEM CSS, Globals, and Class naming

Tags: css, naming-conventions, bem

I'm trying to determine an approach for for standardizing classes in CSS, for use on multiple projects.

I understand that the [BEM](http://getbem.com/) model allows for ease of development by specifying block level elements for stand-alone styling. My concern with this approach is in handling global elements.

**Example:**

I have two "modules": News and Events. Both modules have a listing of their items but on *site 1* the modules are identical, and on *site 2* they have fairly unique styles.

**Current Understanding:**

[This post from 2014](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25611948/bem-css-similar-blocks-and-style-sharing) leads me to believe the best approach would be:

```
<div class="news news--listing module module--listing">...</div>
<div class="events events--listing module module--listing">...</div>
```

I feel that this might be the best approach, since any global styling could be handled under `module__listing`, and if uniqueness is needed specific classes are available.

I have a tougher time with children from here though. Say both have an item listing, how could this be approached well? Example:

```
<div class="news news--listing module module--listing">
    <ul class="news__list item__list">
       <li class="news__item item">...</li>
    </ul>
</div>
```

This feels like going overboard - but I'm not sure of a better solution. Would I just keep this naming convention down the child list?

**Question:**

I am wondering if there are any best approaches to this that I may not be aware of, or of any concerns maintaining this type of approach.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Block, Element, Modifier methodology (BEM)

Using your example, it would be like:

```
<div class="[block]">
    <ul class="[block__element1]">
       <li class="[block__element2]">...</li>
       <li class="[block__element2] [block__element2--modifier]">...</li>
    </ul>
</div>
```

Then your code would look like this:

```
<div class="news">
    <ul class="news__list">
       <li class="news__item">...</li>
       <li class="news__item news__item--selected">...</li>
    </ul>
</div>
```

Notice that a modifier (news__item--selected) is always followed by the element class (news__item).

More info:

BEM Documentation, Quick Start: https://en.bem.info/methodology/quick-start/

BEM by Example: https://seesparkbox.com/foundry/bem_by_example

Answer (score 1):

You may use the concept of [Redefinition levels](https://en.bem.info/methodology/key-concepts/#redefinition-level) to have diffenent styling for same entities on different project and still keeping common code in one place without adding additional `module` entity.