# Style multiple used block specifically by parent block

Tags: html, css, modularity, bem

I am learning about BEM (CSS) methodology and am not sure about the following example:

Suppose I am building a navigation block which I want to use in a navigation bar and also on other places on the page.

```
<div class="navbar">

   <ul class="nav">
      <li class="nav__item"><a href="#" class="nav__link"><?php _e( 'My account', 'phytoreform' ); ?></a></li>
      <li class="nav__item"><a href="#" class="nav__link"><?php _e( 'Log in', 'phytoreform' ); ?></a></li>
   </ul><!--End .nav-->

</div><!--End .navbar-->
```

In the example above you can see the `.nav` block is placed inside the `.navbar`. Which classes should I add to style the `.nav`, `.nav__item` and `.nav__link` inside the `.navbar` bar specifically?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I guess you could find some clues here
[BEM block, naming & nesting](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22566179/bem-block-naming-nesting)

First of all, BEM has a lot of writing variations, so you won't have THE right answer.

In your case, root `.navbar` could be considered as a modifier (instead of a block, as your block is already defined as `.nav`. 
In that case, you could sufix some new classes with `--navbar`
So you could end with something like this

```
    <div class="navbar">
   <ul class="nav nav--navbar">
      <li class="nav__item nav__item--navbar"><a href="#" class="nav__link nav__link--navbar"><?php _e( 'My account', 'phytoreform' ); ?></a></li>
      <li class="nav__item nav__item--navbar"><a href="#" class="nav__link nav__link--navbar"><?php _e( 'Log in', 'phytoreform' ); ?></a></li>
   </ul><!--End .nav-->

</div><!--End .navbar-->
```

Comment: Thanks for you answer. I know there are many variations, but I am trying to find a decent one. In the last documentation of BEM they declare modifiers as follows: `.nav_navbar` instead of `.nav--navbar`. What do you think?

Comment: Very true. As a matter of fact, I still prefer the `--` modifier notation instead of the `_` notation one. First because I find the CSS code readability easier this way (sometimes, not that easy to distinguish a `__` from a `_`). Secondly because on some CSS code legacy, you can find some `_` separator without any BEM purposes.

Comment: Just a matter of preference, but the BEM guidlines suggest nesting for modifiers, so you dont need `nav__item--navbar` on your `<li>`'s, instead in css reference `.nav--navbar nav__item{}`. The benefot of this becomes clear when you toggle modifiers with javascript